# Matplotlib for SUMO

Tags: matplotlib, openstreetmap, simulator, ns2, network-traffic

Is it possible to create plots of vehicles let through on a lane using **matplotlib** in the Python script that acts as as the controller for **SUMO** ?

What if an OSM map were to be used?

I'm asking if this could essentially replace the use of NS-2 dependent Xgraph.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  Could you provide a bit more context?  I suspect the answer is yes, but.......

Comment: SUMO is a simulator for urban traffic that can make use of OSM data to create netlists etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this shouldn't be possible, but you need to do it on your own. You might consider existing scripts as [partyrender](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Party_render).

Maybe a better idea is to use a screenrecorder to make movies out of the animations of the eWorld frontend: http://eworld.sourceforge.net